# SQL Full Outer Join without duplicates with like condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are two tables.

I want to find and join records between two tables with having value -1 or +1.
But in that case it returns me duplicate records also.
How can i get the result without duplicate records?

[image]

```
drop table if exists #A

CREATE TABLE #A(ID float, Category varchar(10), Amount float )
insert into #A values

(1,'A',150.4),
(2,'A',151.0),
(3,'A',149.8),
(4,'A',165.0),
(5,'A',165.0)

drop table if exists #B

CREATE TABLE #B(BID float, BCategory varchar(10), BAmount float )
insert into #B values

(95,'A',151),
(101,'A',150),
(115,'A',165.0),
(118,'A',165.0)
```

i have tried following query, which returns duplicates.

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         ID, category, Amount, 
         row_number() over (partition by category, Amount order by category, Amount) as Sr 
     from #A) A
full outer join
    (select 
         BID, Bcategory, BAmount, 
         row_number() over (partition by Bcategory, BAmount order by Bcategory, BAmount) as Sr 
     from #B) B on a.category = b.bCategory 
                and a.amount between b.bamount - 1 and b.BAmount + 1 
                and a.sr = b.sr
```

Logic: How the current user is mapping manually:-

First, try to Exact match (category and amount) with another table.
Then whatever left try to match Category and Amount with (+/- 1) of TableB.

So 149.8 or 150.4 of A, both any can join with 150 of B. Since only one (150) in Table B is left and 151 already assigned to 151 under exact match, one record of A will be join to null.

Let's say, since 150.4 is appearing first in tableA it can go with 150 of TableB.

And 149.8 will remain unmatched. Practically user does not mind to match with either or. Important is, any one row (150.4 or 149.8) shall match to null. Problem with left or full outer join is, 150 of B is being assigned to both (149.8 and 150.4).

Comment: Can we change the table filed?

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  Why does record B-101 go to A-1 rather than A-3?  Any logic that allows that would seem to assign B-95 instead.

Comment: You say "full outer join" yet your sample data does not have a situation where a row in B does not join to a row in A. Demonstrate this or change your description. In addition, it appears that you want to fabricate and force a 1:1 relationship between A and B yet, by your logic, you have a 1:M. Your first row in A joins to 2 rows in B - why do you pick 150 and not 151? The third row in A is much closer to 150 than the first but it does not join. Seems you also assume that things happen in a particular order as well?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i have updated question with logic applied by user manually.

Comment: @SMor, yes if any record in tableB does not match to table A, then it will show in result with null value on its left columns. For the question of 1:M  match which it should pick, i have updated the question with logic explaining the same. Let me know if i need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique record we need to mapped relation between the table

> Table Definition

```
drop table if exists #A

CREATE TABLE #A(ID float, Category varchar(10), Amount float )
insert into #A values

(1,'A',150.4),
(2,'A',151.0),
(3,'A',149.8),
(4,'A',165.0),
(5,'A',165.0)

drop table if exists #B

CREATE TABLE #B(AID float,BID float, BCategory varchar(10), BAmount float )
insert into #B values

(2,95,'A',151),
(1,101,'A',150),
(4,115,'A',165.0),
(5,118,'A',165.0)
```

> Query

```
SELECT * FROM #A A
LEFT JOIN #B B ON  A.ID = B.AID
```

> Other way

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         ID, category, Amount, 
         row_number() over (partition by category, Amount order by category, Amount) as Sr 
     from #A) A
full outer join
    (select 
         AID,BID, Bcategory, BAmount, 
         row_number() over (partition by Bcategory, BAmount order by Bcategory, BAmount) as Sr 
     from #B) B on a.category = b.bCategory 
                and a.amount between b.bamount - 1 and b.BAmount + 1 
                and a.sr = b.sr AND A.ID = B.AID
```

> OutPut result

[image: Output]

Comment: I do not have AID column in table B. Both tables are already exists with historical data. I cannot have new column like you said AID in tableB.

Comment: Can you add? for testing because we don't have a relationship for both table

Comment: I can add column, but then how i will fill the value in AID? I understand there is no relation, but the logic to build the relation is match exact value, if not then try to match with -1 or 1 value.

Comment: when we insert in #A table then time we got the value and set in #B

Comment: if not then try to **match with -1 or 1 value ** I understood for match and not math

Comment: as i said, i am not creating new tables, both tables are already exists in database with thousands of records. If you want me to add new column Aid and TableB, what value it will have against each record and how that value will be passed?